# Create a data array based on certain fields on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I try to display the array data in the table and it went perfectly, but how to display the data array based on a particular field with major field `name` below is an example of the data in the table.

Example data

```
  |   Name  |   Option  |   Value       
===============================
  | Ahmad   |   High    |   90
  | Smith   |   Low     |   43
  | John    |   Low     |   55
  | Adam    |   High    |   79
  | Smith   |   High    |   80
  | Adam    |   Low     |   55
  | Ahmad   |   Low     |   48
  | John    |   High    |   90
```

And following the data that I expected

```
            |       Option     |
================================            
  |   Name  |   High  |   Low  |     
===============================|
  | Ahmad   |   90    |   48   |
  | Smith   |   80    |   43   |
  | John    |   90    |   55   |
  | Adam    |   79    |   55   |
```

Controllers

```
function detail_data() {            
        $data = array(
            'detail_option' => $this->my_model->model_detail($metadata_code),
        );                  
    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
}
```

Models

```
function model_detail() {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('tb_student')
                      ->group_by('name')
                      ->get();      

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
            $result_data[] = $data;
        }
        return $result_data;
    } 
}
```

Views

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Name</td>
        <td colspan="2">Option</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>High</td>
        <td>Low</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($detail_option as $row) {  
        echo '<tr>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row->high.'</td>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row->low.'</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';   
        }
    ?>              
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
function detail_data() {            
        $data = array(
            'detail_option' => $this->my_model->model_detail()
        );                  
    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function model_detail() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tb_student`");

    $result_data = array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
            $result_data[$data->Name]['Name'] = $data->Name;
            $result_data[$data->Name][$data->Option] = $data->Value;
        }
        return $result_data;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Name</td>
        <td colspan="2">Option</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>High</td>
        <td>Low</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($detail_option as $row) {  
        echo '<tr>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row['High'].'</td>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row['Low'].'</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';   
        }
    ?>              
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is this something you wanted?

Comment: I'll try your scritp

Comment: I removed the err in variable name above.

Comment: Data does not appear all so blank

Comment: That returns your data in array format. use print_r() to show what it returns. post it here.

Comment: i'am write on views `echo  '<td>'.print_r($row->trflp_code).'</td>';` result value = 1

Comment: We're returning as array now. so use `$row['Name']`. Plus, that is not how you `print_r()`

Comment: Nice... Yes works well, but it appears but only one field option that appears  `HIGH` and field `LOW` does not appear???

Comment: You may have to do tweaks. Understand the code and do it yourself. I dont do homeworks. If this answer helped, please mark it correct and help community.

Comment: okay thanks for the help, and it was very helpful I would try to explore again